# Break loop when ajax error

Tags: javascript, loops

I ajax call inside loop and i need to break loop when file not exist. It looks like that:

```
                for(m=1; m<10; m++){    

                    $.ajax({

                        type: "GET",
                        url: "/config/" + m + ".xml",
                        async : false,
                        dataType: "xml",
                        success: function(xml) {

                            alert("File Exist");                                                            

                        },
                        error: function(xml) {
                            alert("File not exist");
                            break;
                        }
                    });
                }
```

When i remove break from error function it will alert that "File not exist" but when i leave that break there it completely break whole script. I just need to break the loop only when file will not exist.

Comment: Actually, your overall approach seems fuzzy. You sure you want to set off 10 requests in a `for()` loop? Why not send one request and let the server handle the rest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    var m=1;
    while(m<10){    

       $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "/config/" + m + ".xml",
           async : false,
           dataType: "xml",
           success: function(xml) {

               alert("File Exist");   
               m++;                         
           },
           error: function(xml) {
               alert("File not exist");
               m=10;
           }
      });
 }
```

Comment: Oh yeah putting m=10 in error is briliant Idea... Thank you very much. That works perfectly now.

Comment: setting the `m=10` is not the solution, rather the `async: false`!

Comment: async=false was one of the assumptions in the question itself. I didn't add it, I simply noticed it.

Answer (score 3):

I would better use something like this:

```
(function loadConfig(n) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/config/" + m + ".xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            alert("File Exist");
            if (n < 9) loadConfig(n + 1);
        },
        error: function (xml) {
            alert("File not exist");
        }
    });
})(0);
```

This will make a non-blocking request which is usually better for UX.

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hhWVs/)

Comment: async=false, the requests are synchronous.

Comment: Now after your edit (removed async), I agree 100%. That's the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should rather consider using a `while` loop to add another conditional (even though you might do that in the `for` loop condition as well

```
var m = 1, fileExists = true;
while ( m<10 && fileExists ){
   $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "/config/" + m + ".xml",
       async : false,
       dataType: "xml",
       success: function(xml) {
           alert("File Exist");                                                            
       },
       error: function(xml) {
           alert("File not exist");
           fileExists = false;
       }
   });
   m++;
}
```

or with the for loop

```
var fileExists = true;
for(m=1; m<10 && fileExists; m++){
    // ...
}
```

Comment: true, with the while/for loop construct you need to set `async: false` otherwise the for loop will not break where you expect it to

Comment: :) same issue, because I made a mistake `fileExist` corrected to `fileExists`